# Bug in Editing help

Tags: bug

In the [Editing help page](https://sports.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), under [Preformatted Text](https://sports.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), there is a section on "Monospace Spans", which reads:

```
`https://`If your browser's location bar starts with , then the connection is encrypted.
```

That should presumably have the `https` in the blank space prior to the comma, one would assume. I'm not sure if it should be entirely in a code block itself or not (it is supposed to represent what you would type in, but that doesn't show the effect very well...)

> If your browser's location bar starts with `https://`, then the connection is encrypted.

This bug appears on many sites, but not all (not on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com) for example, that uses a very different editing help section.)